# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 when using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, maven, xcodebuild, cocoapods

This is only happening on one machine, a Mac mini build server. It has the same error for armv7s. It works on several Ubuntu build agents and my local machine (Macbook Pro). These servers all have the same:

- XCode version (5.0)
- Podfile/Podfile lock
- Pod cache (cleared it on every machine)
- Maven version (3.1.1)
- Cocoapods version (0.29.0)

The pod in use is TTTAttributedLabel:

```
[INFO] Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
[INFO]   "_kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName", referenced from:
[INFO]       -[TTTAttributedLabel commonInit] in libPods.a(TTTAttributedLabel.o)
```

But TTTAttributedLabel is not used as a pod, it's source was pasted directly into another private pod which was added to this project. I don't know why as I didn't develop it and the developer who did is not available. The source of TTTAttributedLabel was customized somehow so I don't feel comfortable changing it as this is a production build.

So I have the main project which includes a private pod which has code from TTTAttributedLabel within it's source code directly.

The private pod does get installed correctly. The TTTAttributedLabel files are included in the private pod's compile sources. libPods.a seems to be linked correctly in XCode. Both the main project and pod's valid architectures are the same (armv7 and armv7s).

I have tried just about every answer I could find on the internet in the last ~6 hours.

Why doesn't this server find these symbols? Why does it work everywhere but here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was cocoapods version 0.23.0 (or something below 0.29.0). Even though the build server had 0.29.0, the build was actually being ran inside of a Rails subshell using Ruby's `system()` command. This meant that it was also using the Rails bundle, which only had cocoapods 0.23.0.

Comment: So what did you do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I has this the other day, I had to clear the cache and then reinstall pods by running the following:

```
rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
pod update
```

Then Clean the workspace by using Cmd+Shift+K

Comment: I did try the first command but not the second with `pwd`. I will try this tomorrow, thanks.